# Android draw out of a class on an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, drawing, draw

Good Morning,

I just started my first android project (but have knowledge in Java, VB, etc).

I'm searching all day long bt untl know I was unable to find an answer to my problem, I find a lot of ways to draw on an empty screen ...
 But I searching a methode to  draw multiple diagramms and so on directly on my MainActivity next to my buttons and other controls. In Java I would have used different drawPanels to get the job down but due to missing swing library I can't proceed that way.
Are their good tutorials out there on that topic or do you have an advice?
 I'm glad for every tipp.

Dwon there / you will find an example of my current try, but as said it will just draw the "BAttery" and not the activity components:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    DrawBattery draw = new DrawBattery(this, 96);
    setContentView(draw);
}
```

-

```
public class DrawBattery  extends View {


private int batteryCharge = 0;   //battery charge in %

public DrawBattery(Context pContext, int pBatteryCharge)
{
    super(pContext);
    batteryCharge = pBatteryCharge;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


...
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling `setContentView()` twice, have your `res/layout/activity_main.xml` put an instance of your `DrawBattery` `View` where you want it.

You may wish to read through [the "Creating Custom Views" portion](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) of the Android documentation.

Comment: Thnx for the hint, but I am not quite sure how I should embebbed my DrawBattery in the xml

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom `View`s. You can create a new class that extends `View`, then override the `onDraw` method (and onMeasure / onSizeChanged if you need).

When you want to draw something to the View, you can, for instance, create a setter / init method on the view that will initialize the data that you want to draw.

Then, put your view(s) inside a custom layout, and inflate an activity / fragment with that layout. If you need more or you need them to be dynamically added you can programatically add them in the code.

Comment: I tried now different things out with the customView(), i managed to draw different Bitmpas out of classes on it. But I can not enable that the activity controls are displayed as well